# Is this the proper way to start my loop?

Tags: python

**Question:** “A movie theater charges different ticket prices depending on a person’s age. If a person is under the age of 3, the ticket is free; if they are between 3 and 12, the ticket is $10; and if they are over age 12, the ticket is $15. Write a loop in which you ask users their age, and then tell them the cost of their movie ticket.”

The reason I put != 'quit' is to give the end user the option of quiting the program. I don't know if that makes sense. This is what I have so far:

```
prompt = 'What is your age? '
age = ' ' 
while age != 'quit':
    age = input(prompt)
    age = int(age)
    if age < 3:
            price = 0
    if age > 3:
            price = 10
    if age < 12:
            price = 15
print('The price of your ticket is ' + price)
```

I keep getting a syntax error on the last print statement.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a good look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  Here, you don't provide output, errors, or expected behavior.  Learning debugging techniques is the Lions share of learning to program, so to of these not as SO skills but as developer skills in general.

Comment: Add break statements after every time you set the price variable.. if you need to type 'quit' as your age to make the loop break, this will always break the line `age = int(age)` so this code will never work properly

Comment: *I can't seem to get it right* is not a problem description, and *Any suggestions?* is not a specific question. When you created your account, it was suggested that you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so,  especially [ask], and then come back and [edit] your post to clearly describe the problem and ask a **specific** question. While you're making that [edit] you can improve the title to something descriptive. The name of the course is meaningless.

Comment: What is the error message ?  *exact error messages should always be included with breaking code*

Comment: *Hints:* What is the value of price, if `age=='quit'` ?  If `age=='quit'`, What is the next line that is run ?  What do you expect the value of `int('quit')` to be?  or `int('jibberish')` ? You can run quick little code snippets to test these out at https://repl.it

Comment: what is the type of `price`?   What is the type of  `'The price of your ticket is'`? Can you `concatenate` (`+`) them? What happens if you do?

Comment: Python code blocks are defined by indentation.  Is your code properly indented ?

Comment: Is `if age < 12` what you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

**Preamble:** In general, you should write what your code is supposed to accomplish.  Also, it would be helpful if you wrote your code in a .py file for my (and anyone else who wants to help) convenience; I can't paste your code in the python interpreter, so I have to paste it in a file but I have to remove all those ">>>" and "...".

In this case, I will deduce that your requirements are

1. Get an age from the user and print it.
2. Validate the input and continue asking for an age until the input is valid.

The problem that you have is that your condition for quitting causes problem:

```
~/Desktop $ python3 stack_overflow.py
What is your age? 32
Age : 32
What is your age? quit
Age : quit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack_overflow.py", line 6, in <module>
    age = int(age)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'quit'
```

So let's get the logic that we want down, then we'll see how to do it in python.

```
<get a valid input>
<decide the ticket price based on said valid input>
```

One thing to note is that in python, since the input is valid if it can be turned into an int we can try to turn it into an int and call the input valid if that conversion succeeds.

By reading error messages we can see that writing 'quit' results in ValueError, we can deduce that this:

```
prompt = 'What is your age? '
age = ' '
input_valid = False
while !input_valid:
    age = input(prompt)
    try:
        age = int(age)
    except ValueError:
        input_valid = False
        continue
    if age > 0:
        break

if age < 3:
        price = 0
if age > 3:
        price = 10
if age < 12:
        price = 15

print('The price of your ticket is ' + str(price))
```

Now, at this point, I think you would have satisfied your requirements.  However, lemme drop some more knowledge on you:

What if you read the following code:

```
age = get_age()
price = ticket_price(age)
print("The price of your ticked is " + str(age))
```

This reminds me of something I saw in a talk on YouTube which I thought was really nice: write code using functions that you wish existed then implement those functions.

```
def get_age():
    while True:
        age = input('What is your age : ')
        try:
            age = int(age)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if age > 0:
            return age

def ticket_price(age):
    if age < 3:
        # Under 3 years old don't pay
        return 0
    if age < 12:
        # between 3 and 12, price is 10$
        return 10
    # 12 and above pay 15
    return 15

age = get_age()
price = ticket_price(age)

print('The price of your ticket is ' + str(price))
```

Also, another tip: whenever I have something like

```
while True:
     ...
     if <something>:
          break
```

It's a good idea to put that while loop in a function and replace the break with a return statement.

Given that I did not have your requirements, I can't be sure I solved your question.  That being said, the main takeaways should be

1. separating the getting of input and the conversion from age to
   price.
2. putting code into functions is worth your time even for toy examples
   like this because it's practice for actual coding.
3. Writing out the logic of your program in pseudo code is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you have set up your loop. It shouldn't terminate if the user enters 'quit' as the age. This doesn't make sense for the rest of your logic with regards to the variable age. Instead of using a while loop, you could instead use a for loop and print the price for a number of users

```
for user in range(5):
    age = int(input('What is your age?'))
    if age < 3: price = 0
    if 3 <= age <= 12: price = 10
    if age > 12: price = 15
    print('The price of your ticket is: $' + str(price))
```